# GridSplitter Autosize

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid, gridsplitter

I got a problem with the `GridSplitter`

Simple example code:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="2"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="TopGrid" Grid.Row="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Red"/>
    <GridSplitter ResizeDirection="Rows" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="2" Background="Black" />
    <Grid x:Name="BottomGrid" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Background="Aquamarine" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

This creates two Grids vertically seperated by a `GridSplitter`.

What I want to achieve is, that the `GridSplitter` automaticly align to the Grid´s content.
For example if I got a collapsable element in the bottom Grid, I want the top Grid to become bigger if I collapse the element. If I expand it, the top `Grid` should become smaller.

How do I do this? Later I will have 4 `Grids` with 3 `GridSplitter`´s... so the solution should work with multiple `GridSplitter`´s as well.

[edit]:

my xaml:

```
 <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100">
            <RowDefinition.MinHeight>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MultiValueConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="dgStapelliste" Path="ActualHeight"></Binding>
                </MultiBinding>
            </RowDefinition.MinHeight>
        </RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="1"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition >           
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Test">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <WPF:DataGrid GridHeaderContent="{Binding StapelListe.HeaderText}" SelectedItem="{Binding StapelListe.SelectedItem}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="dgStapelliste" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding StapelListe, Mode=OneWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <WPF:DataGrid GridHeaderContent="{Binding EinzelListe.HeaderText}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="dgEinzelliste" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  ItemsSource="{Binding EinzelListe, Mode=OneWay}"/>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" Width="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Black" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <WPF:DataGrid  GridHeaderContent="{Binding Anforderungsliste.HeaderText}" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="dgAnforderungsliste" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Anforderungsliste, Mode=OneWay}"/>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" Width="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Black" />
    </Grid>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Height="1" ResizeDirection="Rows"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Black" x:Name="testSplitter" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use MultiBinding to achieve what you want.

For each RowDefinition you set a MinHeight which is bound to its contents ActualHeight's like so:

```
<RowDefinition Height="100">
    <RowDefinition.MinHeight>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=CalcAll}">
            <Binding ElementName="firstElementInThisRow" Path="ActualHeight"></Binding>
            <Binding ElementName="secondElementInThisRow" Path="ActualHeight"></Binding>
            <Binding ElementName="thirdElementInThisRow" Path="ActualHeight"></Binding>
            <Binding ElementName="fourthElementInThisRow" Path="ActualHeight"></Binding>
        </MultiBinding>
    </RowDefinition.MinHeight>
</RowDefinition>
```

Your Converter could look like:

```cs
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    double result = 0.0;
    foreach (object item in values)
    {
        result += System.Convert.ToDouble(item);
    }
    return result;
}

public object[] ConvertBack(object values, Type[] targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return null;
}
```

Everytime you expand a control, its ActualHeight changes and the Binding gets update -> MinHeight of the parents RowDefinition changes.

But you cant set one if the controls VerticalAlignment to Stretch, because then the ActualHeight wouldn't change by expanding.

**EDIT**: Since the only property I can now think of is the DesiredSize.Height-property, you can't use Binding (the binding won't update, if the DesiredSize.Height-value changes).
But perhaps you can use a property (let's call it MinHeightRowOne) of type double which raises the PropertyChanged event in it's setter and is bound to the first rows MinHeight (one property for each row):

```cs
public double _minHeightRowOne;
public double MinHeightRowOne
{
    get
    {
        return _minHeightRowOne;
    }
    set
    {
        _minHeightRowOne = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MinHeightRowOne");
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

```
<RowDefinition Height="100" MinHeight="{Binding Path=MinHeightRowOne}"/>
```

Now add this EventHandler to the SizeChanged-Event of every control in the first row (one handler for each row):

```cs
private List<KeyValuePair<string,double>> oldVals = new List<KeyValuePair<string,double>>();

private void ElementInRowOneSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement elem = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    MinHeightRowOne -= oldVals.Find(kvp => kvp.Key == elem.Name).Value;
    elem.Measure(new Size(int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue));
    MinHeightRowOne += elem.DesiredSize.Height;
    oldVals.Remove(oldVals.Find(kvp => kvp.Key == elem.Name));
    oldVals.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>(elem.Name, elem.DesiredSize.Height));
}
```

Through this the MinHeight of the Rows get updated everytime the Size of a control changes (which should include expanding or collapsing items).

Note that every control must have an unique name to make this work.

Comment: the problem with this solution is that "ActualHeight" is always the height of the row.  if I set the Height of the row to "100", the ActualHeight of the DataGrid in this row is "100" too... it doesn´t sum the scrollable content

Comment: could you please add your xaml in you question?

Comment: hmm can´t really get it to work, since "DesiredSize.Height" won´t change as well. Got the same value as "ActualHeight"...  "100" if I set the "Height" of the row to "100"

Comment: thats strange, actually thats what DesiredSize is made for (getting the bounds even if the element is taller than its parent)...and in my case it did work perfectly (even width rows Height="100").

Comment: didnt you forget `elem.Measure(new Size(int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue));`?